XAMPP Error, anoter web server already running (fedora)
Terminal Image
failed to start apache, because another webserver already running
solution tried so far

disable and stop httpd
reinstall xampp after remove httpd
sudo netstat -nap | grep :80
There are no httpd service
i already killed all of them using sudo kill [number] but nothing is change

(i installed xampp because i need phpmyadmin for school, not knowing that xampp component was already installed by default on fedora)

Why would one want to use XAMPP on a perfectly fine Linux installation that already includes those components? Anyway, you probably only killed the child processes ("prefork"), but those are respawned. The main process might also be called "apache2". If you really deinstalled the apache http server and rebooted, then it certainly is not running any more. Maybe you also have nginx installed?

Thanks for your reply, i need phpmyadmin for school, back then i installed xampp on anoter fedora machine and it works just fine, so i thought i need xampp to access phpmyadmin not knowing i can do that without xampp, 2 days ago i installed all of this : https://www.tecmint.com/install-lamp-fedora-server/, and then when i install xampp this error appear, and i did not have nginx installed, should i install it?

phpmyadmin is a simple php application you can use under any http server that integrates php by whatever means. Sure, XAMPP is an option, but you need to understand what it actually is: it is a distribution of the components apache http server, MySql RDBMS, PHP scripting environment. Those are the exact components that you already installed as a LAMP stact. So you already have all those components intalled. Which is why you now get the conflict. I would always recommend to gi with the packages offered for your Linux flavor instead of using something like XAMPP.

So remove XAMPP, make sure those components you installed as LAMP (that are an absolute standard for any Linux system) are correctly installed and working. It does not really matter whether you use the apache http server or nginx as an alternative. If you are new to this go with the apache variant, you will find much more support and explanations referencing that one. Make sure you also installed the "mod_php" extension for the http server. And you are ready to install and use phpmyadmin.

Alright i'm gonna remove it now, thanks for the advice man you're the best
